# Questionnaire/survey app like Google Form - (python+javascript)

Tags: python, survey

Django-survey or django-questionnaire is too admin-centric for me (beside tied to django). I want my user to create their own survey. Something like Google Form survey (view [example](http://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=dENteVBPMmFiZGFxbm5ZUHFrNFBsRnc6MA)), where form creation feels fluid and intuitive (because of js magic). I've googling around with no luck.

Is there any python-based survey app/library/package out there? I'm OK if i have to write my own model/python-wise but not so sure in designing the creation process (javascript). Do you have suggestion of what Javascript library may suit this?

Thanks.

Comment: i tried embedding google form. see http://github.com/apit/rinjani/blob/master/handlers/misc.py and http://obscurite.ind.ws/article/contoh-embedding-google-form

basically, the real form proxied via my app which it's modified to allow css/js customization (cross-domain css/js problem).

users then only required to write simple tag like {{ survey formId }} to embed form into their content.

dirty, but works. better approachs are welcome though.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried taking a look at [google app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)?
It really is not just a survey library, but much much more - and since it gives you Python APIs it probably is not too hard to create a web service that can be used by your users to create new surveys.

[Here is the python documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) and [here are the docs for form handling](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html)

Comment: Try creating survey form using Google Spreadsheet. You'll see what i mean ;)